# Error while using transformation function in R

Tags: r

I was working with baby names data set and encountered below error while using transform function. Any guidance/suggestion would be highly appreciated. I did reinstalled the packages but of no avail.

Mac OS X (Mountain Lion)

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"

```
 library(stringr)
 require(stringr)
 bnames1 <- transform(bnames1,   
 first = tolower(str_sub(name,1,1)), 
 last = tolower(str_sub(name,-1,1)), 
 vowels = vowels(name),  
 length= nchar(name),   
 per1000 = 10000 * prop, 
 one_par = 1/prop  
 ) 

 Error in tolower(str_sub(name, 1, 1)) : 
lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/stringr/R/stringr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In tolower(str_sub(name, 1, 1)) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
 2: In tolower(str_sub(name, 1, 1)) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Answer (score 0):

`internal error -3` is often a functioning of installing on top of a loaded package. Restart R and restart your application. There may be other issues, but until you do this you won't be going much further.

Comment: After restart are any other errors produced or did this resolve the issue completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
remove.packages("stringr")
install.packages("stringr")
```